# Simple oblivious redirect not working?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

My goal is to redirect access to mydomain.com/foo to mydomain.com/bar.html with:
1- The user not being able to tell where hs is redirected
2- The url being pretty and containing neither file name nor extension nor arguments.

Following a series of examples I found on the matter I have the content of my .htaccess file to be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule    ^/foo$  /bar.html [PT]
```

Which does not work. Requests to mydomain.com/foo give a 404 error.

While I would appreciate a short explanation of why the above example does not work I would much rather be given directions to a proper tutorial on using the rewrite engine; All the ones I found seemed to assume the reader is already literate on various aspect such as the syntax and what it means or the tags ([PT], [R], [L]...?).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule    ^/?foo$  /bar.html [PT]
```

And let me know if it works!

Comment: It doesn't work. What happens is /foo is redirected to foo.html and /bar to /bar.html while non-existing file names like /tup give 404

Comment: Can you put rewrite log here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /bar.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Same behavior as what Death suggested.

Comment: What happens when you directly enter: `http://domain.com/bar.html` in your browser?